# ValueError at /admin/login/ - dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a django project that I haven't touched in about a month. I have comeback to see an error when trying to connect to any page for the app (including admin login page). The error is:

> ValueError at /admin/login/
>   dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required

Here is the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 1.11.4
Python Version: 3.6.2
Installed Applications:
['ad_app.apps.AdAppConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  205.                 with context.bind_template(self):

File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\contextlib.py" in __enter__
  81.             return next(self.gen)

File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py" in bind_template
  263.             updates.update(processor(self.request))

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 0; 2 is required
```

Here is my settings.py file:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '***'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

LOGIN_URL = '/welcome'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['ad_app.authentication.EmailBackend']

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ad_app.apps.AdAppConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ad_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'ad_app.views.wallet',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ad_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I can provide more information if needed!

Comment: Please show the code of `ad_app.views.wallet`. Is that actually a context processor?

Comment: you're absolutely right! i removed that line and it worked, not quite sure what i was doing there, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed line

```
'ad_app.views.wallet',
```

from context processors. Many thanks to Daniel Roseman!